# How to secure WCF service hosted in Azure called from Monotouch?

Tags: wcf, security, azure, xamarin.ios

I have a monotouch application that currently calls a hosted WCF service in IIS using ssl and basic authentication.  I need to move this wcf service to Azure and am confused on the best security practice.  I've read to use ACS, but I can't find any examples of using that setup with monotouch and am not sure it will work.  Does anyone have any examples or suggestions with calling a WCF service from monotouch securely in azure?

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with MonoTouch. But as far as the service side is concerned, you can continue to use SSL and basic authentication. Note by default IIS basic authentication require Windows credential. Since it works locally, I think you’ve already implemented a custom basic authentication module. Another area to note is it needs additional steps to support SSL in Windows Azure. You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg271302 for a tutorial. ACS is usually used if you want to support claim based authorization.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Thank you Ming.  I have SSL setup fine and was using basic auth/active directory when it was hosted in our local server.  From reading some more it appears I can also join the role to our domain and it would solve my issues as well.  I will also need access to our db server on our local network so that may be the best solution at this point.

Comment: Yes, that’s also an option. You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433029.aspx for more details.